# Function that querys database and then renders a view

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im new at backend development and I'm noticing that my code is very messy and difficult to read. I know this doesn't have a single correct answer but id like to know how I can make my code tidier when I have so many queries and const definitions. Thank you!

I have this piece of code from a function that retrieves data from db and then renders a view. Im trying not to use ORMs so I can learn SQL better.

```
show_consorcio_controllers.render_show_consorcio = async (req, res) => {
    const id_consorcio = req.params.id_consorcio;
    const user_id = req.session.passport.user;
    const consorcios = await connection.query("SELECT id FROM consorcios WHERE id_consorcio = ?", id_consorcio);
    const id_admin_del_consorcio = consorcios[FIRST_POSITION].id;

    if(id_admin_del_consorcio === user_id) {
        const consorcio_info = await connection.query("SELECT * FROM consorcios WHERE id_consorcio = ? and id = ?", [id_consorcio, user_id]);
        const consorcio = consorcio_info[FIRST_POSITION];
        const orden_ingresos_egresos = consorcio.order_egresos_ingresos_by;

        let fecha_de_muestra_final = moment(consorcio.fecha_de_muestra_final).format("YYYY/MM/DD");
        let fecha_de_muestra_inicial = moment(consorcio.fecha_de_muestra_inicial).format("YYYY/MM/DD");

        const user = await connection.query("SELECT nombre FROM usuarios WHERE id = ?", user_id);
        const {nombre} = user[FIRST_POSITION];

        const expensas = await connection.query("SELECT unidad_funcional, mes_periodo, anio_periodo, id_expensa, id_consorcio, titulo, monto_total, fecha FROM expensas WHERE id_consorcio = ? AND id_admin = ?", [id_consorcio, user_id]);
        const { ingresos, egresos } = await show_consorcio_controllers.get_ingresos_egresos(orden_ingresos_egresos, id_consorcio, fecha_de_muestra_inicial, fecha_de_muestra_final, user_id);
        const proveedores = await connection.query("SELECT id, nombre, apellido FROM proveedores WHERE id_admin = ?", user_id);

        show_consorcio_controllers.normalize_dates(ingresos);
        show_consorcio_controllers.normalize_dates(egresos);

        const unidades_funcionales = await connection.query("SELECT * FROM unidades_funcionales WHERE id_consorcio = ? AND id_admin = ?", [id_consorcio, user_id]);

        fecha_de_muestra_final = moment(consorcio.fecha_de_muestra_final).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
        fecha_de_muestra_inicial = moment(consorcio.fecha_de_muestra_inicial).format("DD/MM/YYYY");

       res.render("consorcio/show_consorcio", {expensas, unidades_funcionales, proveedores, id: user_id, nombre, id_consorcio, ingresos, egresos, orden_ingresos_egresos, fecha_de_muestra_inicial, fecha_de_muestra_final, consorcio});
    } else {
        res.send("No esta permitido el acceso a esta pagina");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Test for invalid state up front**

Eliminating branching simplifies. The high level reads in a more consistant general
abstraction level.

```
if (! id_admin_del_consorcio === user_id) {
   res.send("No esta permitido el acceso a esta pagina");
   return;
}

// all that code ...

res.render("consorcio/show_consorcio", {expensas, unidades_funcionales, proveedores, id: user_id, nombre, id_consorcio, ingresos, egresos, orden_ingresos_egresos, fecha_de_muestra_inicial, fecha_de_muestra_final, consorcio});
```

---

**Create `Consorcios` object**

Very confusing:   Currently there are two variables named "consorcios" but in different scopes. Then everything
seems to have "consorcios" in the name.  Make an object to manage that. `Consorcios` object properties should not have "consorcios" in their names.

- Pass `res, req` as parameters
- Make the queries into Object methods. Probably still need to pre-populate these.

  - Pre populate in the constructor. Necessary call order is guaranteed and all in one place. And the rest of the code will be cleaner.
  - pass method parameters so we do not need to read all that SQL.
- Make object methods for the variables.

  - fecha_de_muestra_final
  - fecha_de_muestra_inicial
  - {nombre}  ... possibly does not need to be a formal Object
  - { ingresos, egresos }  ... possibly does not need to be a formal Object
  - that inner scope `const consorcio`
  - ... and so on.
- Call the methods when they are used. Don't pre-assign a separate variable.